# Video is broken on Windows 10: affects Chrome / Edge / VLC Player

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, youtube

Youtube has always worked fine on my Chrome (Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit) ) +Win10 Laptop but since yesterday videos don't play. I already restarted and also tried loading youtube in incognito mode. No luck. The page loads just that the video wont play.

Youtube works fine on Microsoft Edge (Version 83.0.478.58 (Official build) (64-bit)). Not sure how to debug this. Already cleared cache in Chrome.

The videos just keep loading for ever. Only error message I get is:

> "If playback doesnt begin shortly try restarting your device"

Any ideas?

[image]

PS. I also switched chrome profiles but same problem.

Add remove programs shows the following recent entries. Could one of these be the problem?

Now it looks like the problem is intermittent and doesn't affect just Chrome. It is the same in Edge, VLC Player etc.

[image]

Comment: Try a clean-up of Chrome from `chrome://settings/reset`

Comment: Update/Reinstall chrome?

Comment: "Don't play" How don't they play? If you're running an ad-blocker, google have changed their ad method & you'll be getting a black playback area with "An error occurred. Please try again later" followed by some oblique ref code. The fix for now is to disable your blocker, until the dev manages to figure out the new method.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks! No ad blocker that I have installed. Any way to check if this has to do with any plugins etc. I tried in Incognito mode and same problem. They don't play meaning the "loading" icon keeps rotating forever.

Comment: @spikey_richie Would a chrome reset remove all my extensions and passwords etc?

Comment: Yes, it would. That's the point - to start with a blank slate to make sure that it's not your extensions or settings that are breaking something.

Comment: I would remove HEVC temporarily.  You can always reinstall it. When you indicate Edge works.  Legacy Edge or Microsoft Edge?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks! Updated in the question.

Comment: The version of Chrome you are using basically is Chromium.  I would backup your Google Chrome profile, delete it, and see if the problem goes away.  HEVC isn’t your problem if Microsoft Edge doesn’t have the same problem by the way.

Comment: @Ramhound So I switched profiles to my dad's who also has used Chrome on this machine before. Still does not work. So doesn't seem profile specific?

Comment: Please perform the test the way I suggested.  You need to backup the entire profile directory, once you do that, delete the entire directory.  Be sure you backup all profiles when you perform this action.

Comment: @Ramhound Looks like I was wrong. The problem is intermittent and affects both Chrome AND Edge. In fact it even affects VLC Player and even MP5 videos inserted into MS Powerpoint from the local drive. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you removed HEVC?  My original comment indicated it was not the problem if and only if Microsoft Edge did not have the problem.  Since you confirmed it does you really should try removing it